# Consultar pela Data

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Bom estou usando o EF com o seguinte código para consultar ele traz a consulta por nome e tipo porém por data não, já que a hora não está em meu filtro com a hora 00:00:00 ele traz corretamente a hora não faz parte da pesquisa, porém faz parte da regra de negocio.

```
public PaginationResult<Tabela> GetAll(ISpecification<Tabela> specification, Pagination pagination = null, Sorting sorting = null)
{
    var query = Tabela.Where(specification.SatisfiedBy());
    var result = new PaginationResult<Schedule>();

    if (sorting != null)
    {
        query = query.OrderBy(sorting.ToString());
    }
    result.TotalItems = query.Count();
    if (pagination != null)
    {
        query = query.Skip(pagination.CurrentPage * pagination.ItemsPerPage).Take(pagination.ItemsPerPage);
    }

    result.Items = query.ToList();
    return result;
}
```

O `specification`

```
specification = 
          specification.And(Specification<tabela>.Create(e => e.data.Equals(filter.data)));
```

Comment: Tem como você editar a especificação do seu problema? Eu não consegui entender nada.

Comment: Bom eu quero ignora a hora na consulta

Comment: Qual o tipo do campo Data ? edite sua pergunta e poste uma classe do seu modelo com o exemplo da chamada do seu método.

Comment: Bom estou refazendo pode deixar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se `a hora não faz parte da pesquisa`, creio que você pode pegar só a porção da data adicionando o `.Date` na data dos objetos quando criar o specification:

```
specification = specification.And(Specification<tabela>.Create(e => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(e.data) <= filter.data.Date));
```

Comment: traz esse  erro: Não há suporte ao membro 'Date' do tipo especificado em LINQ to Entities. Somente inicializadores, membros de entidade e propriedades de navegação de entidade têm suporte.

Comment: Tente remover o `.Date` da expressão do linq:
`specification = specification.And(Specification<tabela>.Create(e => e.data.Equals(filter.data.Date)));` 
Creio que isso resolva.

Comment: Bom ele não da erro, porém não traz nada.

Comment: Então acho que a solução seria não usar o equals e fazer a comparação da seguinte forma: `specification = specification.And(Specification<tabela>.Create(e => e.data.Date  == filter.data.Date));`

Comment: Aconteceu o mesmo erro

Comment: Se estiver usando a partir do EF 6, você pode usar a função `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` para remover a porção da data:
`specification = specification.And(Specification<tabela>.Create(e => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(e.data) == filter.data.Date));`

Caso esteja usando uma versão do EF inferior à 6, use a função `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime` para  isso:
`specification = specification.And(Specification<tabela>.Create(e => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(e.data) == filter.data.Date));`

Comment: Bom aconteceu um outro erro, mas deixa terei que mudar a logica toda da aplicação mesmo, obrigado

Comment: Eu usei <= e funcionou obrigado